# Spark dataframe select operation and number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5.0

I am doing a broadcast join since one of my dataframe is around 30 GB (large_df) and other is around 10 MB (small_df).  Here is my code.

```
 df1 = large_df.join(broadcast(small_df), large_df("col2") === small_df("s_col2")
```

Right after this, if I get the number of partitions for df1, I see the correct number (1000)

```
 df1.rdd.partitions.size() 1000
```

Now I am doing a project to select only certain columns of df1

```
 df2 = df1.select("col2", "col4", "col6", "col8")
```

Right after this, if I get the number of partitions for df1, I see a smaller number (200). I am not sure is it just this select or some other operation is somehow changing the # of partitions of my dataframe.

```
 df2.rdd.partitions.size() 200
```

How do I make sure that the number of partitions is not reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following property of your SparkConf to 1000

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions
```

More info here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html

```
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 
Default: 200   
Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.
```

Answer (score 0):

val df = Seq(
  ("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("A", 3), ("C", 1)
).toDF("k", "v")

df.rdd.getNumPartitions

When ever you do suffle operations on dataframes, the default partitions is 200

val partitioned = df.repartition($"k")

partitioned.rdd.getNumPartitions //Results 200